# powershell : dynamic autocomplete on custom executable

Tags: powershell, autocomplete

So I have a code that generates an executable, and I want to be able to add argument autocompletion on my executable.
I can't even generate a small and easy example from where I could start from. I have looked into the Register-ArgumentCompleter command, but it seems it's made for powershell functions and cmdlets. Maybe I could make my exe a cmdlet with some kind of encapsulation, but I am a bit of a noob in powershell so not sure I know what I'm talking about...

If someone could help me set up a basic example, that'd be great !
for example I have an executable called example.exe (don't care what it does), and when in powershell I run .\example.exe TAB it suggests foo or bar.
That possible ?

Thanks :)

I tried this (and more)

```
$scriptBlock = { 'foo','bar' }
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName .\example.exe -ParameterName Name -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

.\example.exe TAB
=> that shows just the files in current folder

Comment: wouldn't you need `.\example.exe -Name TAB` since the parameter is Name and your completions are the values

Comment: Oh man thank you, I just needed to remove the -ParameterName Name in my code and autocompletion works ! Stupid me for copy pasting the documentation
alright I can get to work now... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ditch the parametername argument. I'd also use just the executable name (if it's in your path environment variable) or the full path to the executable name.

```
$scriptBlock = { 'foo','bar' }
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName example.exe -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

or

```
$scriptBlock = { 'foo','bar' }
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName full\path\to\example.exe -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Now when you type `example.exe TAB` it will complete with `foo/bar`

If you don't want to have to type `.exe` as well, omit it from the definition

```
$scriptBlock = { 'foo','bar' }
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName example -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Comment: I added a proper question about this here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77094920/powershell-layered-autocomplete-arguments