# Powershell: Layered autocomplete arguments

Tags: powershell, autocomplete

So in continuity of my previous question [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77090645/powershell-dynamic-autocomplete-on-custom-executable), I am now trying to have layered argument autocompletion. I have an executable, example.exe.
Currently my powershell looks like this :

```
$scriptBlock = { 'foo','bar' }
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName .\example.exe -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

And what I would like, is that if I decide to add write .\example.exe foo TAB, it suggests foo_sub1 and foo_sub2, and if I have bar, it suggests bar_sub1 and bar_sub2.

I tried looking into [this](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-tab-completion/) but it doesn't really adress my issue, chatGPT wasn't able to help me out either...

Also, in my example, if I do .\example.exe foo and press tab, it'll suggesst foo and bar again, over and over. I would like for it to stop if it has been added once... if someone has some advice here I'll take it as well

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's self-contained sample code that implements the desired logic:

- Tab-complete a partially typed argument via prefix matching against the list of completions
- Exclude already performed completions from completing additional arguments.

The sample list of completions is obtained via `Get-ChildItem -Name *.txt` below, i.e. it tab-completes all `*.txt` files in the current directory.
Replace this command with whatever command determines the list of possible completions for your use case.

```bash
# Note: For versatility, I'm passing 'example' instead of '.\example.exe'
#       as the -CommandName, so that:
#         (a) you needn't type the '.exe' part when completing
#         (b) it'll work for any 'example.exe', irrespective
#             of where it is located.
Register-ArgumentCompleter -Native -CommandName example -ScriptBlock {

  param($wordToComplete, $commandAst, $cursorColumn)

  # Determine ALL completions.
  # PLACE YOU CODE HERE. 
  # In this example, all *.txt files in the current dir. are completed.
  [string[]] $allCompletions = Get-ChildItem -Name *.txt

  # Determine the arguments that have already been specified.
  [string[]] $existingArgs = 
    $commandAst.CommandElements.Extent | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    ForEach-Object {
      $arg = $_.Text
      if ($arg -match "(?s)^(['`"])(.*)\1$") {
        # Remove enclosing quotes, if present, and
        # unescape embedded quotes.
        $arg = if ($Matches.1 -eq "'") {
          $Matches.2 -replace "''", "'"
        } else {
          $Matches.2 -replace '[`"]"', '"'
        }
      }
      $arg
    }

  # Remove completions that have already been used among the existing arguments.
  [string[]] $remainingCompletions = 
    if ($existingArgs) {
      Compare-Object -PassThru $allCompletions $existingArgs |
      Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<='
    }
    else {
      $allCompletions
    }
  
  # Find matching completions by prefix-matching the current word against
  # the remaining completions.
  [string[]] $matchingCompletions = 
    if ($remainingCompletions) { $remainingCompletions -like "$wordToComplete*" }

  # Output the results.
  if (-not $matchingCompletions) {
    $null # Prevent fallback to default completions    
  }
  else {
    $matchingCompletions.ForEach({
        if ($_ -match '[ ''"`,;(){}|&<>@#]') {
          # (Single-)quote the argument, if it contains metachars.
          "'{0}'" -f ($_ -replace "'", "''")
        }
        else {
          $_
        }
      })
  }

}
```

Note:

- The `-Native` switch is used for *external ("native") programs*, whose parameters PowerShell knows nothing about, so it cannot be combined with `-ParameterName`; it limits the arguments passed to the `-ScriptBlock` block to the following positional parameters (whose names you may choose):

  - `$wordToComplete`, the argument on which tab-completion was invoked.
  - `$commandAst`, an AST (abstract syntax tree) of type [`System.Management.Automation.Language.AST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.ast), whose `.CommandElements` property is the collection of tokens making up the external-program call: the executable and its arguments.
  - `$cursorColumn`, the 1-based index of the terminal column where the cursor is currently placed.
- `$commandAst.CommandElements.Extent | Select-Object -Skip 1` therefore represent all arguments specified so far.
- [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) is used to eliminate already-completed values among the arguments specified so far.
- `$remainingCompletions -like "$wordToComplete*"` then takes advantage of the [*filtering* capability of PowerShell's comparison operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#common-features) such as [`-like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like), where using an *array* as the LHS returns the *subarray of matching elements* rather than a single `[bool]` value (`$true` or `$false`):

  - Appending [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) character `*` to `$wordToComplete` therefore returns all those remaining completions that *start with* the word to complete (if the word is empty, *all* are returned).
- Note that the code also supports arguments that have *embedded spaces* or other PowerShell metacharacters, by single-quoting them on demand on *returning* completions, and by removing any quotes for comparisons on *finding* completions.

  - It is unfortunate that this quoting and unquoting must be done *manually*.
  - [GitHub issue #11330](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11330) discusses a future improvement, but there hasn't been any activity since 2020.
- See also: the [`Register-ArgumentCompleter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-argumentcompleter) docs.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to your input mklement0, I was able to reach my full use case

```
Register-ArgumentCompleter -Native -CommandName example -ScriptBlock {

  param($wordToComplete, $commandAst, $cursorColumn, $lowestLevel)

  # Define custom completions for "foo" and "bar"
  [string[]] $customCompletions = 'foo', 'bar'

  # Determine the arguments that have already been specified.
  [string[]] $existingArgs = 
    $commandAst.CommandElements.Extent | Select-Object -Skip 1

  # Check if the user has already typed "foo" or "bar"
  $userInput = $commandAst.Extent.Text
  if ($userInput -like "example foo*") {
      $customCompletions = 'foo_1', 'foo_2'
  }
  elseif ($userInput -like "example bar*") {
      $customCompletions = 'bar_1', 'bar_2'
  }

  # Check if the user has reached a point where no further suggestions are needed
  if ($userInput -like "example foo foo_1*" -or $userInput -like "example foo foo_2*" -or
      $userInput -like "example bar bar_1*" -or $userInput -like "example bar bar_2*") {
      $customCompletions = @()
  }

  # Output the result.
  if (-not $customCompletions) {
      $null # Prevent fallback to default completions
  } else {
      $customCompletions
  }

}
```